# Datatables server side processing with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, datatables, server-side

I am using datatables 1.10+ in my project. I am using MSSQL as my backend. To do server side processing, i have used an old server side scripting found here: 
https://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mssql_odbc

Everything is working well including dynamically passing values to that script. My problem is:
How can i get that script process a filtered query string instead of having all records in the supplied table. That is initially execute a query like

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE Ax='10'
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM sTable
```

Hope i am clear with my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you filter here ` $sQuery = " SELECT * FROM $sTable ";

Comment: No its returning all records without filtering